# Wrap text when 10 character fullsize Katakana

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<p>` tag and in menu

```
<p>日本刀日本刀日本刀日本刀</p>
```

but I want wrap text when text over 16 byte

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS `width` on the `<p>`?

Comment: impossible, my div can't set width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using some simple steps: 8 is set for number of characters you want to wrap

```js
var p = $('p'), string = p.text();

if (string.length > 8) {
  var stringToWrap = string.substring(0, 8);
  p.html(string.replace(stringToWrap, '<span>'+ stringToWrap +'</span>'));
}
```

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>日本刀日本刀日本刀日本刀</p>
```